# Bootstrap offcanvas prevent closing of offcanvas when you click on datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, off-canvas-menu

I am having problems with offcanvas menu closing when i use datepicker in form inside menu and click on datepicker button.

I've been busting my head for last 2 days but i can't make a fix for it and everywhere i searched i didn't find solution.

I am using `jquery ui` and datepicker in combination with bootstrap offcanvas from `iamphill`

https://github.com/iamphill/Bootstrap-Offcanvas

I have some inputs in offcanvas menu and datepicker field on one input, and when i open menu and click on any date or previous/next on datepicker, offcanvas menu closes it self.

Code is very long to paste here so i made codepen example

https://codepen.io/lonerunner/full/dapzNX

If you take a look, you will see small black square in right corner, when you click on square, offcanvas menu will open and on third input field is datepicker, when you click datepicker will open and if you click on next month, offcanvas menu will close.

If anyone have idea how to prevent close i would gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What also works is to change following code to make it *not* close on the datepicker:

*Line 253*

```
  Offcanvas.prototype._documentClicked = function(e) {
    if($('.ui-datepicker').is(':visible')) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this one works on mobile phone too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Offcanvas.prototype._documentClicked function. Line 256 (e.g.):

```
if (!clickedEl.hasClass('offcanvas-toggle') && clickedEl.parents('.offcanvas-toggle').length === 0 && clickedEl.parents('.navbar-offcanvas').length === 0 && !clickedEl.hasClass('navbar-offcanvas') && !clickedEl.hasClass('ui-corner-all')) {
```

Comment: Your both answers are correct and this was damn fast response, thank you guys, but i will have to mark other one as accepted because that one also worked on phone.